# Puppeter Save returned value from page evaluate as a csv

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, puppeteer

I currently have a puppeteer script, that fetches information from a website by getting an array of all hrefs on the page, looping through each href link, and then fetching the data from each respective href link.

After using the page.evaluate function, I was able to return all desired values via return.

How can I write the values of return in to a csv?

Here is my script:

```
const stealth = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')();
 


const hrefsCategoriesDeduped = new Set(await page.evaluate(
    () => Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll('.b-shared-linked-pharmacy__box a[href].b-shared-linked-pharmacy__details'),
      a => a.href
    )
  ));


  let pages = [];

console.log (hrefsCategoriesDeduped)

for (const url of hrefsCategoriesDeduped) {

    await page.goto(url);
   // await page.waitFor(10000)
    let telusData = {   
      name: "",
      address: "",
      city: "",
      province: "",
      postal: "",
      fax: "",
      pharmacyphone: "",
      pharmacyfax: "",
      pharmacyemail: "",
      pharmacywebsite: ""
    };
    await page.waitForSelector('.b-pharmacy-detail__details');
    //let pharmacycomplete = []

    telusData =  await page.evaluate(() => {
 let pharmacyname  = document.querySelector('h2[class="b-pharmacy-detail__name"]').innerText
 let pharmacystreet = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".b-pharmacy-detail__info"), element => element.textContent)
 let pharmacyphoneandfax = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".b-pharmacy-detail__contact"), element => element.textContent)

var variable_names = {};
for(var i = 0; i< pharmacystreet.length; i++){
  variable_names['na_'+i] = pharmacystreet[i];
}


return {
  name: pharmacyname,
  address: pharmacyaddress,
  city1: city[1],
 province: province[1],
 postal: postal[1],
 pharmacyphone: pharmacyphone,
 pharmacyfax: pharmacyfax,
 pharmacyemail: pharmacyemail,
 pharmacywebsite: pharmacywebsite,

 }
});

console.log(telusData)

  }



    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Right now, I declare variable TelusData with all the headers for csv, then do a page evaluate to receive the value for the headers and the corresponding values.
I return :

```
return {
  name: pharmacyname,
  address: pharmacyaddress,
  city1: city[1],
 province: province[1],
 postal: postal[1],
 pharmacyphone: pharmacyphone,
 pharmacyfax: pharmacyfax,
 pharmacyemail: pharmacyemail,
 pharmacywebsite: pharmacywebsite,

 }
```

For each 'telusdata' how can I save the values of the data into a csv with the headers as well? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you just stuck on creating the actual csv? Take a look at: https://csv.js.org/project/examples/

Comment: I'm stuck with generating the CSV in the desired format (I want it to post all values in return)

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to build a `TelusData` object for each URL, then generate a csv with each url's data. If so, you just need to push each object into an array as you build them, then use that array to generate your csv.

Comment: Exactly, yeah, but it'd want each data from url with telusdata  in 1 csv. Can you show an example of that, with some test data?

Comment: I'll add an answer to point you in the right direction since code blocks in comments are limited... one second...

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reduced your code a bit since there was a lot that had nothing to do with your specific issue. Hopefully this can point you in the right direction.

```
(async function main() {
    try {
        // create array to store all the data
        let telusDataArray = [];

        for (const url of hrefsCategoriesDeduped) {
            telusData = await page.evaluate(() => {
                return {
                    name: pharmacyname,
                    address: pharmacyaddress,
                    city1: city[1],
                    province: province[1],
                    postal: postal[1],
                    pharmacyphone: pharmacyphone,
                    pharmacyfax: pharmacyfax,
                    pharmacyemail: pharmacyemail,
                    pharmacywebsite: pharmacywebsite,
                }
            });
            telusDataArray.push(telusData); // add each url's data to the array
        }

        // at this point telusDataArray should be filled and ready for CSV generation

        await browser.close();
    }
})();
```

Comment: It seems to be working much better now, thanks. Quick question, when I try to export to CSV, the result simply outputs [object Object]. How can I get the value of object. I suspect this is because i'm switching objects into strings. Any idea?

Comment: That is the output if you try to log pretty much any generic object in js. If you're trying to output JSON you can use `JSON.prettify(data, null 2);` or if you're using the csv library you'll need to check the api for output functionality.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to assist! I was able to JSON.Stringify the object, and derive the data. Everything works like a charm now :-)